# Getting query parameter in AngularJS Resource transformResponse function

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to create simple "database" in json file, and service for it with function to get specific item from json parsed array.
I'm using sample modified code from angular tutorial:

```
var projectService = angular.module('projectService', ['ngResource']);

projectService.factory('Project', ['$resource', '$http',
function($resource, $http){
    return $resource('assets/data/projects.json', {id: '@id'}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                //problem
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

I see that correct parameter is passed during ajax call the whole contect of json file is returned, and I cannot access the url param to filter the array to get correct object.
Is there any way to access url params in transformResponse function?

Comment: The second argument in the $resource provider, paramDefaults, is designed to contain the default URL parameters for parameters states in the first argument, the url. Your URL does not have an :id parameter in it, so in all cases it will just return the whole JSON object.

Comment: @horyd - yeah, I know that passing parameter to url containing only json file will always return the whole content of the file, and I just want to filter the content of the file manually, but I can't get the url parameters I passed with the request, cause I see that the parameter is correctly passing into request e.g: build/assets/data/projects.json?id=projectId

Comment: Ah I see. I looked into the docs on $resource a bit more but I can't find a way to do what you're thinking unfortunately. Sorry :(

Comment: @horyd - no problem at all, I ended up using $location service, and just parse current url which also had the id i was needed. This isn't ideal solution, but it's enough for me. Thanks for the help :)